# Angular 5 Firebase Display logged in User's Username in Frontend

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular5

I tried to do a Firebase Angular 5 Login and then I tried to print the displayName or whatever Data in the Frontend.

auth.service

```
export class User {
  uid: string;
  username: string = "";
  constructor(auth) {
    this.uid = auth.uid
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authState: any = null;
  currentUser: User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router) {
    this.afAuth.authState.switchMap(auth => {
        if (auth) {
          this.currentUser = new User(auth)
          return this.db.object(`/users/${auth.uid}`)
        } else return [];
      })
      .subscribe(user => {
          this.currentUser['username'] = user.username
      })
   }

   get currentUsername(): string {
    return this.authState['displayName']
  }

  signUpWithEmail(email: string, password: string, username: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName : username
      });
      this.authState = user
      this.db.object(`/users/${this.currentUser.uid}`).update({"username": username})
      this.isLoggedIn()  
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        throw error
      });
  }

  loginWithEmail(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        this.authState = user
        this.isLoggedIn()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        throw error
      });
  }


  isLoggedIn() {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        console.log(auth);
      } else {
        console.log('User logged out');
      }
    });
  }

}
```

login.component

```
onSignUp(): void {
    this.clearErrorMessage()

    if (this.email, this.password, this.username) {
      this.authService.signUpWithEmail(this.email, this.password, this.username)
        .then(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home'])
        })
        .catch(_error => {
          this.error = _error
          this.router.navigate(['/'])
        })
    }
  }


  onLoginEmail(): void {
    if (this.validateForm(this.email, this.password)) {
      this.authService.loginWithEmail(this.email, this.password)
        .then(() => this.router.navigate(['/home']))
        .catch(_error => {
          this.error = _error
          this.router.navigate(['/'])
        })
    }
  }
```

& in the frontend I tried 
{{ authService.currentUsername }}
which is working. But only once. When I reload the page, the console tells me it can't find the displayName.
I wonder how I can access currentUser - or can I the way I implemented everything?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproduction of your issue?

Comment: I don't know how I could do this.

Comment: No problem, here's a good guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you can put your example on plunkr after reading this guide

Comment: I think if you reload the page you are logged out again, hence the username will be empty/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. That is what worked for me.

Just use:

```
this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser
```

where `angularFireAuth` is

```
constructor( private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth ) {}
```

It will give you locally stored (I believe) logged in user.

[More to read here ...](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Comment: Thnx. But where do I use this? Where do I paste it?

Comment: If you have problem here "in the frontend I tried {{ authService.currentUsername }} which is working. But only once. When I reload the page, the console tells me it can't find the displayName." Then use it in `get currentUsername()` instead of `return this.authState['displayName']` use `return this.authState.auth.currentUser.displayName`.